# why * used before declaring a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to learn python. I was following an example where they have used * before declaring a variable. My question is that what is the purpose of using this. 
Example, I am following

```
for i in range(n):
  name, *l = input().split()
  s = list(map(float, l))
  a[name] = s
```

After printing the variable I get a dictionary, which is made by a. But can't understand why * used before l variable

Comment: it's for unpacking the rest of the data into a list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a new unpacking feature introducted in python 3 called star unpacking or [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

when you do

```
name, *l = input().split()
```

the result of `split` is divided in 2 parts:

- `name` gets the first element of the list
- `l` gets the rest of the list (the floats)

so suppose you have a line like this:

```
name 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

`split` sets `name` to `"name"`, and `l` takes `["0.0", "1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]`. `l` is converted to a list of floats by `list(map(float ...`

Then `name` is used as a key and the list of floats as values.

Aside: your loop can be summarized in a dictionary comprehension like below:

```
a = {name:list(map(float,l)) for name, *l in (input().split() for _ in range(n))}
```